# Showing the polynomials form a Gröbner basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ real matrix in row echelon form and $I \subset \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an ideal generated by polynomials $p_i = \sum_{j = 1}^na_{ij}x_j$ with $1 \leq i \leq m$. Then the generators form a Gröbner basis for $I$ w.r.t. some monomial order.

So I guess one should try the standard lexicographic order $x_n > \dots > x_1$ first? Since these are linear, aren't the leading terms automatically the same as the $p_i$?

Comment: Why not $x_1>\cdots>x_n$ first? It looks like a natural guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This holds in a more general setting: if the leading terms are pairwisely coprime, then the $S$-polynomials reduce to zero. (For instance, whenever $\gcd(\mathrm{LT}(f),\mathrm{LT}(g))=1$ one can write $S(f,g)=-(g-\mathrm{LT}(g))f+(f-\mathrm{LT}(f))g$.)

In your case every monomial order for which the variables are ordered according with the corresponding columns of the matrix work. This is Exercise 1.6.5 from *An Introduction to Gröbner Bases* by Adams and Loustaunau.